# Does gem log unrecognised options with whitespace?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rubygems

I'm seeing a somewhat peculiar error in Jenkins where a gem is being invoked correctly, but the error is spitting out an option with a whitespace character between the options identifier (`--`) and the option name (`checksum`).

```
gemname publish_artifact --version 0.1.0 --checksum 01fakechecksum89 --repository release

publish_artifact: unrecognised option -- checksum
```

I checked the Jenkins node and the option is available. I haven't run the command because the deployment is not mine to make, I'm just on the ops team and am not really that familiar with Ruby yet.

I ran a command with a fake option for a different gem and got a different error response.

```
$ yard list --fakename blah
[warn]: Unrecognized/invalid option: --fakename
```

Notice no whitespace between the option specifier and the name. I'm digging into the Jenkins pipeline configuration because it is quite complex, and maybe the command is getting butchered between the master and the node, but it just doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a rather misleading error. The problem was that gem failed to update to the newest version. The older version didn't have the `checksum` option.